# "a right way" or "in a right way"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, expressions

I heard a lot people omit the "in" while saying "in a right way".

for example

if a kid play with a knife, someone would told him/her "you are not using the knife a right way"

is it grammatical and idiomatic?

Comment: Usually I would replace **a** with **the** in both cases. In which case, full example makes perfect sense, but I am not sure if it is technically grammatical.

Comment: As per the above comment, I have never heard *using **it** a right way*, only *using it **the** right way*.

Comment: To echo the sentiments above, there's usually only **one** right way, so it's *the* right way, not *a* right way.  Seeing  "a right way" immediately tells me I'm dealing with a non-native speaker.  It's definitely *idiomatic* to omit the "in" in this construction -- "you are not using the knife the right way" sounds fine and might even be preferable.  Like @katatahito, I'll leave the grammatical analysis to an answerer.  For what it's worth, I'd *personally* just use "correctly" and avoid the whole thing: "you're not using the knife correctly"

Answer (score 2):

This question was already answered in the comments, however for the sake of completeness -

Both your sentences are grammatically correct when a is replaced by the.

> You are not using the knife the correct way
>
> You are not using the knife in the correct way